# Change background color in message from HipCHat

Tags: colors, message, hipchat

Is it possible to change background color in message from HipCHat? I cannot find anysing useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of a notification message when sending it [via the api](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/send_room_notification). You need to set the 'color' attribute in your JSON payload.

Changing the color of regular messages is not supported at the moment.